# trying to implement spring without IDE annotation based javaconfig approach

Tags: java, spring

Hi I'm trying to implement spring 3.2 example using `@configuration` annotation:

1. I have written my service interface : intf.java
2. Implemented service interface : impl.java
3. written Appconfig class which is replacing xml based approach of
   injecting beans

Here I annotated Appconfig class with `@configuration`.

Written a method that would create instance to `impl.java` and returns intf as reference

Annotated this method with `@Bean(name="hw")`.

Used these two imports:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
```

4.Written class with Main method

Here I created instance to `ApplicationContext` using `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` given my `Appconfig.class` as argument to this on context reference, called `getBean` method "`hw`" casted and receiving intf reference on intf ref, calling my service method.

used imports are:

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;<br>
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
```

set classpath to `spring-context-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar`

I receive compilation errors as follows:

```
AppConfig.java:1: error: package org.springframework.context.annotation does not exist
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
                                   ^
AppConfig.java:2: error: package org.springframework.context.annotation does not exist
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
                                   ^
AppConfig.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
@Configuration 
                                   ^
symbol: class Configuration
ConfigReadMain.java:1: error: package org.springframework.context does not exist

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
                                   ^
ConfigReadMain.java:2: error: package org.springframework.context.annotation does not exist
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
                                   ^
AppConfig.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
 @Bean(name="HW") ^ symbol:   class Bean
location: class AppConfig
ConfigReadMain.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
ApplicationContext actxt = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
                                   ^
symbol:   class ApplicationContext location: class ConfigReadMain
ConfigReadMain.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
ApplicationContext actxt = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
                                   ^
symbol:   class AnnotationConfigApplicationContext
location: class ConfigReadMain
HelloWorldImpl.java:3: error: printHelloWorld(String) in HelloWorldImpl cannot implement printHelloWorld(String) in HelloWorldInf void printHelloWorld(String msg){
                                   ^
attempting to assign weaker access privileges; was public
9 errors
```

Comment: The formatting fixes made a big improvement in readability; thanks.

Comment: @Tim welcome sir, all for the community!

Answer (score 1):

8 of your 9 compilation errors appear to be because the `spring-context` JAR isn't on your classpath.  I know your question says you've got it on the classpath, but the compilation errors suggest otherwise.  What are you using to compile?  And are you using different technologies to edit your code vs. to build it?  (e.g. Editing in Eclipse, but building in Ant.)  If so, make sure that that JAR is on the classpath for both technologies.

The last one appears to be because you declared your interface method as public but your implementing class isn't public.  (Maybe it's default, maybe protected, maybe private, we can't know since you didn't post that code, but either way, just make it public and you'll be good.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the command line to compile and manage your [spring framework application](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/), you are totally on the wrong way!

Letting go a wonderful [IDE](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Java_IDEs) like [eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/) with [spring plugins](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/spring-tool-suite-sts-eclipse-kepler-43) which suit perfectly with your application!

If you ask me, I use all that stuff above and I almost manage to get something out of my web application, and what about you?

I mean to run and compile a hello world application with notepad and command line is ok,

But an application as complex as [Spring Framework 3](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/), you gotta be kidding me.

It's the time to use  a serious [IDE](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Java_IDEs).

***`Note: All the keywords in my answer are hypertexts to enable you surf instantly a proper site.`***

Comment: More generally, your IDE shouldn't be what's performing your build, it should be Ant/Maven/Gradle/etc.  Ideally your build technology and your IDE would integrate seamlessly so you wouldn't have to keep them in sync, but even if you were using Emacs as your editor, you should still have an external build technology by the time you get around to deploying anything to production.